# Error: Cannot find module './proto' on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, connect, express

I can't seem to figure out why this works locally fine, but when I push it to **Heroku** it fails with the following error.

**Error from Heroku**

```
Starting process with command `node web.js`

module.js:337
    throw new Error("Cannot find module '" + request + "'");
          ^
Error: Cannot find module './proto'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:337:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
    at require (module.js:375:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/connect.js:14:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
Process exited with status 1
State changed from starting to crashed
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "divtest",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "dependencies": {
    "underscore": "1.3.x",
    "crypto": "0.0.x",
    "knox": "0.3.x",
    "mongoose": "~3.1.2",
    "mime": "1.2.x",
    "express": "3.0.x",
    "request": "~2.9.203"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.6.x",
    "npm": "1.0.x"
  }
}
```

`./proto` is a local module that `connect` is calling

I've blown away my `./node_modules` folder and did a `npm install --save` and still get the same results.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?  I can't find a way to determine what version of each package is supported on Heroku.

Comment: The solution was to remove `node_modules` from `.gitignore` and push up my node_modules folder to Heroku. This solved the problem and compile is much faster too.

Comment: I didn't even know that could be done.  I had to hard-code full version numbers into the package.json to get mine to work, but this looks like a much better solution.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue, and my problem was that I'm a git beginner and hadn't properly committed all of the files that were needed. It looks like there was a proto.js in connect somewhere.

I did a git add * (...) and pushed again and it all went nicely.

Another telling error, was that on push Heroku complained about unmet dependencies.